# how to remove border from UIVIEW

Tags: swift

I want to know if there is a way to remove the border from view in swift after I have done this:

```
func addRightBorderWithColor(color: UIColor, width: CGFloat) {
    
    let border = CALayer()
    border.backgroundColor = color.cgColor
    border.frame = CGRect(x: self.frame.size.width - width,y: 0, width:width,
                          height:self.frame.size.height)
    self.layer.addSublayer(border)
}
```

I have tried this ->

```
func removeBorder(){
    self.layer.sublayers?.removeAll()
}
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: Try this ```self.layer.sublayers?.forEach({$0.removeFromSuperlayer()})```

Answer (score 0):

1. You should simply save your own reference to this layer, rather than using `sublayers`. Using `sublayers` is not prudent as there might be layers other than your border layer.

   Thus:

   ```
   weak var borderLayer: CALayer?

   func addRightBorderWithColor(color: UIColor, width: CGFloat) {    
       let border = CALayer()
       border.backgroundColor = color.cgColor
       border.frame = CGRect(x: bounds.maxX - width,
                             y: bounds.minY, 
                             width: width,
                             height: bounds.height)
       layer.addSublayer(border)

       self.borderLayer = border
   }

   func removeBorder() {
       borderLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()
   }
   ```

   This obviously assumes that this was for a subclass of `UIView` and not an extension. If for the latter, you’d have to use an associated object to keep track of the border layer.
2. Note, one should not use `frame` when figuring out where to place the sublayer. Always use `bounds`.
3. Taking it a step further, you may want it to  gracefully respond to `frame` changes, too:

   ```swift
   override func layoutSubviews {    
       super.layoutSubviews()

       borderLayer?.frame = CGRect(x: bounds.maxX - width,
                                   y: bounds.minY, 
                                   width: width,
                                   height: bounds.height)
   }
   ```